# How to implement list with infinite scrolling in both direction with LiveData

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-paging

I am trying to implement a list similar to "Schedule" view from [Google calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar). Requirements are:

- The list should be infinitely scrollable in both vertical directions.
- The items should come from [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) so the items can update themselves in the UI when they change in database.

I tried using [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging), but it seems that:

- [PositionalDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PositionalDataSource) allows infinite scrolling only in one direction
- [ItemKeyedDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/ItemKeyedDataSource) does not use LiveData
- [PageKeyedDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PageKeyedDataSource) is not applicable because the database query is not based on paged keys

I could not ways to get around the three issues above. Can anybody help me implement this?

Comment: same requirement that i currently looking for. Do u find anything ?